# Screen orientation in android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, screen-orientation

I am having problem using the emulator.

**Problem:** Though my emulator in portrait mode, my home screen displaying in landscape mode.

**Screenshot**

[image]

---

**Settings of the Emulator**

- Platform: Android 3.0
- API Level: 11
- [image]

Note: I don't have problem running this in API Level 8

Comment: Android 3.0 ? It's quite rare to use this OS version to develop Apps. Only a very small percentage of Android devices use Android 3.0

Comment: Try changing the orientation by pressing Ctrl+F12 or NUm 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 3.0 (and all 3.X versions) are only available for tablets, not for phones. Therefore their default orientation is landscape, not portrait. Select a tablet device such as the `10.1" WXGA (Tablet) (1280x800; mdpi)` and it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Android 3.0 sdk are designed for large screens only (i.e. tablets). You can get more idea about this on official documentation of this version [Android 3.0](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.0-highlights.html) After this The next version of [Android 4.0](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.0-highlights.html) Ice-cream Sandwich was designed and optimized for both portrait and landscape mode.

You can set orientation to portrait in your manifest file to fix orientation for your app and you can change orientation of your emulator by pressing ctrl+F12